# "No Dropzone found for given element" error when upload heavy files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm having an issue with dropzone.js where it reports this issue when uploading many "big" files (by big I mean 3-5MB each)

> Uncaught Error: No Dropzone found for given element. This is probably
>   because you're trying to access it before Dropzone had the time to
>   initialize. Use the `init` option to setup any additional observers on
>   your Dropzone

Everything works fine with uploading small files (100-300kbs)

Does anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: if you have many drop zone you must init each one of them specificly

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you forgot to give dropzone an ID.

You can use the component in the following way.

```
{{drop-zone url='http://localhost/dummy' addfilehere=(action "addfilehere")
 id="uniqueID" addRemoveLinks=true autoProcessQueue=false}}
```

and in the component where you use the dropzone you can add the following reference to your ID

```
this.set('dropzone', Dropzone.forElement('#uniqueID'));
```